# Set property default value before instantiation

Tags: c#, reflection, orm

I have a class named Student :

```
public class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

When I create an instanse of Student class , it is null .

```
Student s = new Student();
```

" **s.ID is null** , **s.Name is null** and **s.Age is null** ."

I want to set a default value for Student class , so when I create instanse of it :

```
Student s = new Student();
```

" **s.ID = 1** , **s.Name = Parsa** , **s.Age = 20** "

In the other word , I want to **change declaration or implementation of property getter or override it**.

How can I do this ?

**Update**

I khow I can do this with Static class or define Constractor , but I do not have access to Student class and I want it Not-Static .
I think this problem can be solved with **Reflection**

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: so you cannot use constructor of `Student` class for this?

Comment: No because I don't have it .
I am using reflection , and my class library User define this class.

Comment: And why did you add a tag for 'reflection' ? Are your creating your instance with reflection?

Comment: You should mention that you can't change the class declaration in ur question.

Comment: Why do you need reflection ? what stops you from setting the values via an object initializer ?

Comment: I just want to change Getter implementation .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to initialize the field the the value you want as a default.  For example:

```cs
class MyClass
{
    int value = 42;

    public int Value
    {
        get {return this.value;}
        set {this.value = value;}
    }
}
```

You can use the DefaultValue attribute to inform designers of this non-zero default:

```cs
class MyClass
{
    int value = 42;

    [DefaultValue(42)]    
    public int Value
    {
        get {return this.value;}
        set {this.value = value;}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have access to your Student class you simply can wrap your class into another one with properties that get and set Student class's properties and inside the new class constructor define the default values as you wish.

Comment: It is not usefull for Dll user , I want to fill user-defined class properties with default data.

Comment: Can you try to add "default value attribute" for each property and get it by reflection?

Comment: Not exactly !
Define default value for property (with reflection) so dll user can get it .

Answer (score 1):

Simplely create a constructor with default values assigned:

```
public Student(){
   this.ID = 1;
   this.Name = "Some name";
   this.Age = 25;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> When I create an instanse of Student class , it is null .
>
> " s.ID is null , s.Name is null and s.Age is null ."

Firstly, `Age` and `ID` can't be null because they're value types not reference types.

Secondly, the member variables don't return any useful data because the properties are not initialised hence for numeric types it will be 0 and for reference types it will be null.

> I want to set a default value for Student class , so when I create
>   instanse of it :
>
> Student s = new Student(); " s.ID = 1 , s.Name = Parsa , s.Age = 20 "

There are three solutions which I can think of:

**Solution-1:  Object initializers**

```
Student student = new Student { ID = 1, Name = "Parsa", Age = 20 }; // from C# 3.0
```

**Solution-2:  auto property initializers**

```
public class Student{
     public int ID { get; set; } = 1; 
     public int Name { get; set; } = "Parsa"; // C# 6 or higher
     public int Age { get; set; } = 20;
}
```

**Solution-3: Using a constructor**

```
public class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public Student(int id, String name, int age){
       this.ID = id;
       this.Name = name;
       this.Age = age;
    }
}
```

call it like this:

```
Student s = new Student(1,"Parsa",20);
```

Comment: I know these , But unfortunatly I could not tell my goal very well :(

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    private int _id = 0;
    public int ID
    {
        get
        {
            return _id;
        }
        set
        {
            _id = value;
        }
    }
    private string _Name = string.Empty;
    public string Name 
    {
        get
        {
            return _Name;
        }
        set
        {
            _Name = value;
        }
    }

    private int _Age = 0;
    public int Age 
    {
        get
        {
            return _Age;
        }
        set
        {
            _Age = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For the record I prefer the constructor answers.  I was just trying to show him how to have defaults.